# Gaussian random function

Tags: matlab, noise-generator

By using [normrnd](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/normrnd.html), I would like to create a normal distribution function with mean and sigma values expressed as vectors of size 1x45 varying from 1:45 and plot this simulated PDF with ideal values.

Whenever I create a [normrnd](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/normrnd.html)  like the one expressed below,

```
Gaussian = normrnd([1 45],[1 45],[1 500],length(c_t));
```

I am obtaining the following error,

```
Size information is inconsistent.
```

The reason for creating this PDF is to compute Chemical kinetics of a tracer with variable gaussian noise model. Basically i have an Ideal characteristics of a Tracer now i would like to add gaussian noise and understand how the chemical kinetics of a tracer vary with changing noise.

Basically there are different computational models for understanding chemical kinetics of tracer, one of which is Three compartmental model ,others are viz shape analysis,constrained shape analysis model.

I currently have ideal curve for all respective models, now i would like to add noise to these models and understand how each particular model behaves with varying noise

This is why i would like to create a variable noise model with [normrnd](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/normrnd.html) add this model to ideal characteristics and compute Noise(Sigma) Vs Error -This analysis will give me an approximate estimation how different models behave with varying noise and which model is suitable for estimating chemical kinetics of tracer.

```
function [c_t,c_t_noise] =Noise_ConstrainedK2(t,a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,td,tmax,k1,k2,k3)

    K_1   = (k1*k2)/(k2+k3);
    K_2   = (k1*k3)/(k2+k3);
    %DV_free= k1/(k2+k3);

    c_t = zeros(size(t));
    ind = (t > td) & (t < tmax);
    c_t(ind)= conv(((t(ind) - td) ./ (tmax - td) * (a1 + a2 + a3)),(K_1*exp(-(k2+k3)*t(ind)+K_2)),'same');
    ind = (t >= tmax);

    c_t(ind)=conv((a1 * exp(-b1 * (t(ind) - tmax))+ a2 * exp(-b2 * (t(ind) - tmax))) + a3 * exp(-b3 * (t(ind) - tmax)),(K_1*exp(-(k2+k3)*t(ind)+K_2)),'same');

    meanAndVar = (rand(45,2)-0.5)*2;
    numPoints = 500;
    randSamples = zeros(1,numPoints);
    for ii = 1:numPoints
        idx = mod(ii,size(meanAndVar,1))+1;
        randSamples(ii) = normrnd(meanAndVar(idx,1),meanAndVar(idx,2));
        c_t_noise = c_t + randSamples(ii);
    end
    scatter(1:numPoints,randSamples)

    dg = [0 0.5 0];
    plot(t,c_t,'r');
    hold on;
    plot(t,c_t_noise,'Color',dg);
    hold off; 

    axis([0 50 0 1900]);
    xlabel('Time[mins]');
    ylabel('concentration [Mbq]');
    title('My signal');

    %plot(t,c_tnp);
end
```

The output characteristics from the above function are as follows,Here i could not visualize any noise

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "*varying from 1:45*"? The first two arguments of `normrnd` is the mean and sigma of the distribution used to generate your random numbers. Also, what is `[1 500]`?

Comment: @Jacob I need 500 random values each with different mean and different sigma, not sure if i am correct in my expression

Comment: before anyone can accurately answer your question you need to explain yourself more clearly. Also, what does varying and the mean and variance tell you about a specific function's PDF when the function itself keeps changing randomly between samples

Comment: you are unable to visualize noise because your noise values compared to the values you are plotting are very small. Noise of +/- 1 will not compare with values over 1000, it will not be visible. Also just note, do not just blindly copy and paste stuff into your code that people post and expect it to 100% fit your needs, especially when the problem is not stated clearly from the beginning, you may need to tweak what I had written and make it fit your specific needs.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 :Yes i will change the code accordingly ,i have just posted to give you rough idea about the ideal characteristics..How could i possibly increase my noise to a level that i could visualize noisy output. also how should i plot Noise VS error output, do i have to plot the difference between c_t and c_t_noise and randomSamples

Comment: I think you should think about your noise model. First off, why do you increase the mean of the noise? This will just move the mean of your signal. Secondly, do you want a model where noise increases over time? Or do you just want to see how the signal behaves with different types of noise?

Comment: @Silas, I am not interested in different noise models, any noise which is varying w.r.t time is fine with me,but mean must be constant and sigma must be variable, I would like to keep my mean constant and vary Sigma as i have requested repeatedly i am more interested in generating some noisy data with Sigma varying w.r.t time and plotting c_t(ideal curve),c_t_noise(noise curve) and finally Error curve(Noise(variable Sigma) VS error ( error between c_t and c_t_noise)... The error curve encapsulates how with varying noise the error of signal chances

Answer (score 1):

The only remotely close thing to what you want to be done can be done as follows, but will involve looping because you can not request 500 data points from only 45 different means and variances, without the assumption that multiple sets can be revisited.

This is my interpretation of what you want, though I am still not entirely sure.

**Random Gaussian Function Selection**

```
meanAndVar = rand(45,2);
numPoints = 500;
randSamples = zeros(1,numPoints);
for ii = 1:numPoints
    randMeanVarIdx = randi([1,size(meanAndVar,1)]);
    randSamples(ii) = normrnd(meanAndVar(randMeanVarIdx,1),meanAndVar(randMeanVarIdx,2));
end
scatter(1:numPoints,randSamples)
```

The above code generates a random 2-D matrix of mean and variance (1st col = mean, 2nd col = variance). We then preallocate some space.

Inside the loop we chose a random set of mean and variance to use (uniformly) and then take that mean and variance, plug it into a random gaussian value function, and store it.

the matrix `randSamples` will contain a list of random values generated by a random set of gaussian functions chosen in a randomly uniform manner.

**Sequential Function Selection**

If you do not want to randomly select which function to use, and just want to go sequentially you loop using modulus to get the index of which set of values to use.

```
meanAndVar = (rand(45,2)-0.5)*2; % zero shift and make bounds [-1,1]
numPoints = 500;
randSamples = zeros(1,numPoints);
for ii = 1:numPoints
    idx = mod(ii,size(meanAndVar,1))+1;
    randSamples(ii) = normrnd(meanAndVar(idx,1),meanAndVar(idx,2));
end
scatter(1:numPoints,randSamples)
```

Comment: I have explained my problem more clearly , let me know if you require the more detailed information about how i modelled different kinetic models

Comment: I am more concerned about what you want the function to return or how you want it to behave.

Comment: I want my function to display a plot (Noise VS error) of both ideal characteristics c_t  and the ones with noise padded c_t_noise, my function must compute the error between c_t and c_t_noise and plot the figure for c_t,c_t_noise this graph is expressed in terms of concentration vs time, and another graph which basically gives (Noise VS error) --Where noise is expressed with varying Sigma and mean and error is in between c_t and c_t_noise, i have created a model function(Ideal one) above kindly verify it

Comment: How i could possibly increase the amount of noise when i plot the generated noise,i could only see a small range of values,i would like to visualize my data with high noise signal

Comment: multiply the random numbers generated by a constant, the simple act of multiplication will not affect it being gaussian.

Comment: :After padding noise I would like to estimate the parameter value K3 in the function, could you please let me know how i could possible perform parameter estimation, i understand how it is done for non linear functions,but i could not accurately estimate parameter value K3 after reading the examples in mathworks

Comment: I can't do the whole problem for you, sorry. You really need to take some time, look at your problem and do some thought of your own. I feel like you truly do not understand what you are trying to do, and without that we can not help. Try things, do not expect answers to be given to you.

Comment: :In the above function code which i have written K1,K2,K3 represent rate constants for a Kinetic model,i would like to examine the sensitivity of Kinetic model by examining Rate constant K3 and how Noise effects K3 rate constant, first i modelled Kinetic model(stated in code), I have added gaussian noise to the model,Now i would like to estimate K3 value without noise and K3 with noise   and plot the characteristics of K3 error value with variable noise-This is what i wish to accomplish-This is central theme of my work at present

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this statement

```
Gaussian = normrnd([1 45],[1 45],[1 500],length(c_t));
```

is that you supply two mu values and two sigma values, and ask for a matrix of size [1 500] x length(c_t). You need to pass the size in a uniform way, so either

```
Gaussian = normrnd(mu, sigma,[500 length(c_t)]);
```

or

```
Gaussian = normrnd(mu, sigma, 500, length(c_t));
```

Then you should make sure that the size of the mu/sigma vectors match the size of the matrix you ask for. So if you want a 500 x length(c_t) matrix as output you need to pass 500 x length(c_t) (mu,sigma) pairs. If you only want to vary one of mu or sigma you can pass a single value for the other parameter

To get N values from a normal distribution with fixed mean and steadily increasing sigma you can do

```
noise = @(mu, s0, s1, n) normrnd(mu, s0:(s1-s0)/(n-1):s1, 1,n)
```

where s0 is the lowest sigma value and s1 is the largest sigma value. To get 10 values drawn from distributions with mu=0 and sigma increasing from 1 to 5 you can do

```
noise(0,1,5,10)
```

If you want to introduce some randomness in the increase of sigma you can do

```
noise_rand = @(mu, s0, s1, n) normrnd(mu, (s0:(s1-s0)/(n-1):s1) .* rand(1,n), 1,n)
```

Comment: I am interested in creating a gaussian noise function with variable Sigma and mean, Not sure if i have modelled by equation appropriately ,let me know where i have made a mistake

Comment: what is s0 and s1 here

Comment: could you please let me know what is exactly wrong in my coding when i create noise in this manner  :   for sigma = 1 :50      noise =normrnd(2,sigma,[1,500]); end... this for loop even generates noise i could not understand what is wrong in my initial statement

Comment: :Could you please let me know how i can possibly estimate the value of K3 once i pad the noise to my signal c_t, I understand the function model is nonlinear , i would like to estimate the Value of K3 with noise and without noise ,kindly let me know how i can perform parameter estimation in this context,i have referred to some examples in mathworks but those examples are quite vague.