# Optimize the Function through fminsearch or fmincon

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, fminsearch

I have an  function which describes the characteristics of Tracer in human brain

The output `c_t` is a relation between tracer concentration and time.

The rate constants K1,k2,k3 describe Kinetic rate constants of the Compartmental model

following is my  function

```
function c_t = K3_ErrorEstimates_timescan(t,k3)   
   K_1   = (k1*k2)/(k2+k3);
   K_2   = (k1*k3)/(k2+k3);
   DV_free = k1/(k2+k3);

   c_t = zeros(size(t));
   ind = (t > td) & (t< tmax);

   c_t(ind) = conv(((t(ind) - td) ./ (tmax - td) * ...
           (a1 + a2 + a3)),(K_1*exp(-(k2+k3)*t(ind)+K_2)),'same');

   ind = (xdata >= tmax);

   c_t(ind) = conv((a1 * exp(-b1 * (t(ind) - tmax))+ a2 *  ...
           exp(-b2 * (t(ind) - tmax))) + a3 * ...
           exp(-b3 * (t(ind) - tmax)),(K_1*exp(-(k2+k3)*xdata(ind)+K_2)),'same');

   axis([0 50  0 1400]);
   xlabel('noise');
   ylabel('concentration [Mbq]% error');
   title('Model :Constrained K2');
end
```

I would like to optimize the parameter K3 of above function  using inbuilt matlab optimization instruction fminsearch and fmincon

Kindly let me how i should use `fminsearch`  and `fmincon` to estimate a parameter in a function

The initialization value for k3 are

```
k3 =0.07;
```

rest of the values will remain constant and the values are as follows

```
t=0:0.1:60;
td =0.3;
tmax=0.8;
a1=2501;
a2=18500;
a3=65000;
b1=0.5;
b2=0.7;
b3=0.3;
k1=0.014;
k2=0.051;
k3=0.07;
```

Comment: I will only give some hints: the official documentation on [fminsearch](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) says you need an minimizing function and a starting value. The minimizing function for example could be least squares between the model and the data. The model and the data you already have, so only the minimizer and reasonable starting values are missing.

Comment: @Trilarion, The starting Values for k3 are 0.07,Could you please let me know how i could possibly write a minimizer

Comment: It appears to me that you are turning in circles and asking the same question [over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091987/parameter-estimation-of-kinetic-model) and [over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066521/gaussian-random-function) again. Or, if these questions are indeed all different, why does the code look the same? Are you familiar with the concept of a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Comment: @Schorsch,The question is different, the mathematical model is same, so when you look the code it might look same,but mathematical model is either 2 tissue compartmental model, or Tissue comparmental model with constraint K2 or K3